# Display a true / false as a yes / no with if / else statment jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

I want to display a user status as "active: yes". I don't know how to write the if else statement. I've tried writing it myself, but it still shows "active: 1" I have tried to do a if else statement myself, but it doesnt work.

```
<script>
    let jUser = {
        "name":"A",
        "lastName":"B",
        "active": 1
    }

    $('#lblName').text(jUser.name)
    $('#lblLastName').text(jUser.lastName)

    //if else statement here: 

    if ('active' == '1') {
        $('#lblActive').text("yes")  
    }
    else if ('active' == '0') {
        $('#lblActive').text("yes") 
    }

    $('#lblActive').text(jUser.active)

    $('.navlink').click( function(){ 
        $('.navlink').removeClass('active')                 
        $('.page').hide() 
        $(this).addClass('active')                          
        let sPageToShow = $(this).attr('data-showPage')     
        $('#'+sPageToShow).show()
    })

</script>
```

Right now the output is whatever I write, but I want to display it as yes or no.

Thank you

Comment: you're comparing a string (active) against a numeric string (1/0) - this will never meed the conditional. You need to actually get active value - not use a string

Comment: Firstly you're comparing strings, not the value in the variables. Secondly both sides of your `if` condition (if it worked) do the same thing...

Comment: And what’s wrong with writing `jUser.active == 1` in the if? And the corresponding thing in the `else if` ?

Comment: `if(jUser.active === 1 || jUser.active === 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

- You're comparing the string literal values `active` and `1`, not the value held in any variables
- `active` is a property of `jUser` so it should be `jUser.active`
- `jUser.active` holds an integer, not a string. While an implicit comparison would work, it's better practice to compare the same types.
- You overwrite the `text()` in the last statement so the `if` is redundant
- Both sides of the `if` condition do the same thing

Also note that if `active` has only two possible states (presumably `1` or `0` in your example) then it would make more sense for it to be a boolean `true`/`false` value.

With all that in mind you can achieve your goal with a simple ternary expression:

```js
let jUser = {
  "name": "A",
  "lastName": "B",
  "active": 1
}

$('#lblActive').text(jUser.active === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No');

/*
// the same logic in a full 'if' condition:
if (jUser.active === 1) {
  $('#lblActive').text('Yes');
} else {
  $('#lblActive').text('No');
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Active: <label id="lblActive"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm new to this so I'm trying to understand the logic. It helps a lot with the explanation. And it works!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: I did, but I got this feedback: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the variable by wrapping it in quotes `''`. And `active` is inside `jUser` you need to access it by using `jUser.active` or jUser["active"]. And remove `$('#lblActive').text(jUser.active)` after your if blocks

```
if (jUser.active === 1) {
    $('#lblActive').text("yes")  
}
if (jUser.active === 0) {
    $('#lblActive').text("no") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were comparing a string to a number, which would never do anything.  You need to compare the `active` property on the `jUser` object to the number `1`, and then set some display text of "yes" or "no"

```
let jUser = {
    "name":"A",
    "lastName":"B",
    "active": 1
}

$('#lblName').text(jUser.name)
$('#lblLastName').text(jUser.lastName)

let activeStatus = jUser.active === 1 ? "yes" : "no";
$('#lblActive').text(activeStatus);

$('.navlink').click( function(){ 
    $('.navlink').removeClass('active')                 
    $('.page').hide() 
    $(this).addClass('active')                          
    let sPageToShow = $(this).attr('data-showPage')     
    $('#'+sPageToShow).show()
})
```